# Injecting into games (Similar to xFire)

Tags: .net, vb.net, xfire

How does xFire place itself inside of games?  Thanks if you can.  I'm using vb.net so anything .net is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with xFire in particular, but, in general, under windows, if you want to inject elements of your app into another, you've only got a few choices.

1) if the target app provides an API to facilitate it, use that. This is similar to adding buttons and task panes etc to an MSOffice app for instance.

2) if there's no api, things get a lot more difficult. You can hook into the global Mouse and keyboard events and monitor for specific keys/buttons, even when the game actually has focus. You can also do tricks like using the windows API "SetParent" to effectively "move" a window of yours into another process's window (like the game's). then position your window appropriately and it "looks" like your app is part of the target app. This is pretty tricky business. Not impossible, but there's a lot of get right to keep things from crashing constantly.

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I'll take a look into your method.  I still think there should be a way.

Comment: One thing is to try and determine whether they are actually injecting themselves into the game or just watching for the game onscreen and "positioning" their windows such that it looks like theyre part of the game. I've never used xFire though, so I couldn't really answer that.

Comment: I think XFire uses hooks into the various DirectX libraries to draw a transparent overlay on top of the game window, which passes events that it doesn't care about on down to the next layer.